# Questions incorrectly tagged [streams]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

I have noticed that [most of the questions tagged as [streams]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/streams) are about I/O in general rather than the STREAMS framework that the tag's wiki describes. Perhaps the tag is a little ambiguous?

Answer (score 6):

STREAMS is rather obscure. Additionally, STREAMS is normally written all-uppercase but tag names are in lowercase. So it's understandable that people see [streams](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/streams) and don't realize that it refers to some concept they don't know about. (Tag wiki? Who reads tag wikis?)

I don't think there's an ideal solution but renaming the tag should help. How about [sysv-streams](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sysv-streams)?